# English speaker finding work in Netherlands

Tags: united-kingdom, eu, eu-citizens, netherlands, working

I am 19, I have Scottish qualifications (No University degree/College diploma) and the only work experience I carry is a paperboy.

I do know more than the basics of Dutch as I have Dutch friends and have been speaking with them and been actively learning Dutch on and off for the past 6 months. So I'm fluent in English and basic Dutch. How would I go about finding a job? Prefererrably in the IT/Engineering field. I would looking to be living in Groningen.

I'm not picky on the job, for me anything that would help get the bills paid legally.

I don't particularly have a lot of money, I'd probably be able to save enough for 1-2 month rent max.

Thanks alot for any answers.

Comment: I think this is a dupe, and also pretty broad (see [help]). I'm closing it as such, but if you disagree, please do let us know and we can consider it.